# Is irreducibility preserved under module-finite extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R\subseteq S$ is a module finite extension of UFDs and $r\in R$ is irreducible, is $r$ irreducible as an element of $S$? If this is not true in general, are there results where this is true under additional hypothesis?

Comment: 2 in Gauss domain is not irreducible, 2=(1+i)(1-i), Guass domain is Z[i].

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that this is not true in general, as wxu's example of primes in $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$ demonstrates. I do not have full knowledge in this area, but I have seen some conditions for maintaining irreducibility in the context of quadratic extensions $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{M})$ and $\mathcal{O}_F. $ The following theorem is one example:

$Theorem$. Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $p\in \mathbb{Z}^+$a prime. If $2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$, i.e., $\nexists x\in\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $2\equiv x^2(mod \space p)$  $\implies p$ remains irreducible in $\mathcal{O}_F. $

Let me know if you'd like a sketch of the proof, although I gather your main interest is the result. There is a generalization of this theorem, where, instead of $2$, we consider all squarefree $M$. However, that theorem is beyond my scope; I recommend a basic text in Algebraic Number Theory for more information.